# Where are KDE user workspace appearance settings saved?

Tags: linux, kde

I have the Ghost theme installed in my KDE desktop, which applies to `Application Appearance` color scheme, `Workspace Appearance` window decorations, and `Workspace Appearance` desktop theme settings in the `System Settings` application.

Now that I have everything configured like I want it, I'd like to be able to add the settings to `/etc/skel` so it's available by default to all users.

Can someone point me to where such settings are saved?

Comment: I don't use KDE, but if they're following the standard, the settings would possibly either be in  ~/.config or in ~/.local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workspace settings are in one of the so-called hidden directories under your home directory, e.g., `~/.kde` (see [documentation](https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/KDE_Filesystem_Hierarchy)).

You may find it challenging to [templatize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/templatize) these files for use in `/etc/skel`, though I do see the notion mentioned in a few bug reports, e.g, Red Hat [#89153](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=89153).  The KDE documentation linked above is a good place to start.  The [KDE forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=124546) has some further hints.

Comment: Yep, the files in question are located in `~/.kde/share/{apps,config}`. And you are also correct that I might find it challenging to put them in `/etc/skel`. However, it's not a templatizing issue, it's an issue with the `/etc/skel/.kde` issue not being copied over to a new user's account when created.

Comment: Good answer, but ... templatize? Please....

Answer (score 0):

Besides `~/.kde`, also look at `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` where the latter contains many of the widget settings (eg. QuickLaunch ...)